# How to set the background image of an DIV in CSS?

Tags: css

How to set the background image of an DIV in CSS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
background-image: url('image path');
```

Put this block of code in your CSS to set the background image.

Answer (score 7):

Put this in your `<DIV>` class or ID block:

```
background-image:url('../img/bg.png');
```