# How to overlay a bootstrap grid on top of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an image that I want to set as the background. On top of that image, I'd like to be able to use Bootstrap's grid. Here's the code I have so far:

## HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <img src="..." alt="Background image">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <!-- An image -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <!-- Text -->
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <!-- Text -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
            <!-- ... -->
    </div>

    <!-- More rows -->
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
}

.container img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
}
```

#### Edit:

I should mention that the only way I can access the image is in the HTML. I'm developing a Shopify theme, so to get the image I do:

```
<img src="{{ section.settings.image | img_url:'master' }}" alt="Background image">
```

So using

```
background-image: url(...);
```

doesn't work in my case as I don't know the path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the background image of an DIV in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905579/how-to-set-the-background-image-of-an-div-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can implement this style to the image.

```
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   object-fit: cover;
   z-index: -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass image as background image for the container.

```css
.container {
  background-image: image;
}
```